# Find package-private fields and methods Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I almost never use the so-called package-private acess level (I don't really see the point of it; this could be a follow-up question) and I sometimes forget to add an explicit access level modifier, so:

Is there a way to find (and possibly even automatically replace with "*private* access") all the fields and methods that were declared package-private in a Java project in Eclipse?

Comment: There is one usage for package private functions: they are easily unit tested.